# If $f:\omega_1 \to \omega_1$ is a bijection, then must the fixed points of $f$ contain a club?

Tags: set-theory

I was reading some notes and we have the result that

> If $f:\omega_1 \to \omega_1$ is a continuous bijection, then the fixed points of $f$ contain a club.

I followed that proof's constructive argument, but can it be proven that any bijection's fixed points contain a club? Here's my idea.

Assume there's no club $F$ such that $\forall \lambda \in F, \lambda \leq f(\lambda)$. Then the set $A = \{\alpha : \alpha > f(\alpha)\}$ is not a club. Then by Fodor's lemma, $f|_{A}:A \to \omega_1$ would give us some $\alpha < \omega_1$ such that $f^{-1}|_{A}(\alpha)$ is statioanry. This is a contradiction since $f$ is a bijection.

Now assume there's no club $F$ such that $\forall \lambda \in F, f(\lambda) \leq \lambda$. This means that $A = \{\alpha < \omega_1 : \alpha < f(\alpha)\}$ is stationary. In other words, $\{\alpha < \omega_1 : f^{-1}(\alpha) < \alpha\}$ is stationary. Then $f^{-1}|_{A}: A \to \omega_1$ is regressive. Apply Fodor's lemma again to get a contradiction.

Thus we get that $C_1 \cap C_2$ being the fixed points of $f$ which is a club. Is this proof true? It does not seem intuitively true at all that ANY bijection has this property, and I feel like there's some mistake I'm making.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This means that $A = \{\alpha < \omega_1 : \alpha < f(\alpha)\}$ is stationary. In other words, $\{\alpha < \omega_1 : f^{-1}(\alpha) < \alpha\}$ is stationary.

This last deduction is wrong.  The latter set is $f(A)$, but the fact that $A$ is stationary does not imply that $f(A)$ is also stationary.

A bijection $\omega_1\to\omega_1$ can have no fixed points at all.  For instance, you can partition $\omega_1$ into pairs and have $f$ swap each pair.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: In fact *any* subset of $\omega_1$, which is not the complement of a singleton, is the set of all fixed points of some bijection $f:\omega_1\to\omega_1$. @GoodMorningCaptain